# How should I define Stylus hash values containing commas?

Tags: variables, stylus

I found I wasn't able to set [Stylus hash](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/hashes.html) values to have commas in them using either the curly braces and colons syntax or the brackets and strings syntax. Wrapping the values with `"` or `'` would result in those characters being output as part of the value.

Currently, I have:

```
fonts-serif = Georgia, serif
fonts-sans-serif = Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif

fonts = {
    serif: fonts-serif,
    sans-serif: fonts-sans-serif
}
```

Using these values:

```
font-family: fonts.serif
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options here:

a). You can escape `,` inside the values:

```
fonts = {
  serif: Georgia\, serif
}

body
  font-family: fonts.serif
```

b). You can use `unquote` built-in function and wrap values in quotes:

```
fonts = {
  serif: "Georgia, serif"
}

body
  font-family: unquote(fonts.serif)
```

Comment: or `fonts = { serif: unquote('Georgia, serif') }` and then `font-family: fonts.serif`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be making a mixin named font-family

```
  font-family(x)
    title   = 'Georgia', 'Times new Roman'
    content = 'helvetica', Arial
    code    = 'JetBrains Mono', 'Fira Code', monospace

    fonts = title content code

    if x in fonts
      font-family x
    else
      error('invalid font-family')
```

Usage:

```
.some-title
  font-family title
```

Why this approach is better you may ask?

- variables for fonts are now not exposed to outside world
- intuitive usage
- gives custom error when not used properly